# Erro no tratamento de exceção(try) em python

Tags: python, exceção, python-2.7

Estou fazendo um programa que faz cálculos numéricos, porem constantemente me aparecem operações onde há divisão por `0 (zero)`. Eu acabei arrumando uma solução usando `if`, mas mesmo assim queria saber porque o `try` não consegue tratar essa exceção

```
def substituicoesRetroativas(A,b):
    n = len(b)
    x = zeros(n)
    for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
        soma = 0
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            soma += A[i,j] * x[j]
        try:
            x[i] = float(b[i] - soma)/A[i,i]
        except:
            print "Matriz Impossivel"
            break
    return np.matrix(x).transpose()
```

Ao executar me aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro

```
    Eliminacao de Gauss : 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/PASSINI/Trab 2/sS.py:23: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  x[i] = float(b[i] - soma)/A[i,i]
/home/ubuntu/workspace/PASSINI/Trab 2/sS.py:20: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  soma += A[i,j] * x[j]
[[ nan]
 [-inf]
 [ inf]]
```

Comment: vc teria um exemplo de parametros para a funcao?

Comment: vc esta usando alguma biblioteca neste código?

Comment: @JeandersonBarrosCândido estou usando o numpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O "try não trata a exceção" pelo simples motivo de que não há uma exceção - como você pode ver no terminal, você tem "warnings", não exceções.

Você pode alterar o contexto do NumPy para que ele passe a gerar exceções em vez de preencher os valores com Inf e NaN-  veja a documentação aqui:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html  -

Ou seja, você pode fazer suas operações dentro de um bloco `with` com o `errstate` setado para "raise" em vez de "warn" e então o bloco  try/except funcionará normalmente.

```
In [3]: import numpy as np
In [4]: with np.errstate(divide='warn'):
...:     a = np.array((3,))
...:     a / 0.0
 ...:     
/home/...: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide

In [6]: b
Out[6]: array([ inf])

In [7]: with np.errstate(divide='raise'):
   ...:     a = np.array((3,))
   ...:     b = a / 0.0
   ...:     
   ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FloatingPointError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2107f07a3b75> in <module>()
      1 with np.errstate(divide='raise'):
      2     a = np.array((3,))
----> 3     b = a / 0.0
```